# No QAudioDeviceInfo::availableDevices on Windows

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community to make a Qt-based GUI in C++ which includes a microphone input. I'm testing the microphone part, and am looping through QAudioDeviceInfo::AvailableDevices(QAudio::Mode::AudioInput) (and AudioOutput for that matter) and nothing is coming up. I've checked that my project includes QtMultimedia, and I definitely have audio devices on this computer. I'm stuck with an existing compiled Qt (since this application is plugging into another project), but I've verified that the Qt install has the QtMultimedia and the Windows audio plugins. The Qt version is 5.9.3.

The only thing I can think of is that the project isn't including the right plugin, but I don't know how to change that.

Comment: It seems to me that you do not have the backend installed, in the following link you will find the information about the necessary backend and its version: https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_Multimedia_Backends

Comment: I don't see anything on there which suggests I need to install a backend -- the only applicable backend is "Windows Multimedia" which sounds like it's just the default backend.

Comment: Qt assumes that you have those libraries installed, I do not indicate that in those links indicates that you have to install them, but there are the library lists that you need that you have installed with respect to the OS, Qt does not install those libraries for various reasons, for example licenses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I needed to run "windeployqt" on the built executable to get all of the plugins into the right place. I'm curious why it didn't work without that, but that's a VS + Qt plugin problem, not a Qt problem.